# Converting chunk of NSData to NSString

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm new to iOS and I'm trying to transfer an a file. This code works fine when the sending device is iphone 5c to iPad but it send NULL when trying to send it from ipad to Iphone over Bluetooth4.0

```
NSData *chunk = [NSData dataWithBytes:self.dataToSend.bytes+self.sendDataIndex length:amountToSend];
NSLog(@"Chunk%@",chunk); 
didSend = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:chunk forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:chunk encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Sent: %@", stringFromData);
```

Also iphone gets following output in notification began

```
CBCharacteristic: 0x15da1d90 UUID = EB6727C4-F184-497A-A656-76B0CD5C633A, Value = (null), Properties = 0x10, Notifying = YES, Broadcasting = NO
```

Comment: Are the two devices on the same iOS Version?

Comment: Yes.both are on ios7.do they need to be on same platform (version )?

Comment: Not necessarily. But you could be using a method that only exists on iOS7.
Could you log `self.dataToSend.bytes+self.sendDataIndex`?